# Notification comes again when app starts

Tags: android

As a beginner, I wrote a code for notification. I put that code in MainActivity. 
Now the problem is, my app shows notification at sharp 8 AM. But During other time, if i restart my app, it shows notification again(at any other time). Basically I am not cancelling it notification as it appears. Though I have put AutoCancel true. Am i missing something?

Code in MainActivity, onCreateMethod:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent ;
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationBroadcasrReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("NotificationType","GoodMorning");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(), (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

After this it comes to BroadCast Receiver :

the code inside onReceive is

```
Intent intentNew = new Intent(context, CustomIntentService.class);
    intentNew.putExtra("NotificationType",intent.getStringExtra("NotificationType"));
    context.startService(intentNew);
```

Now custom intent servcice class has following code..

```
        Intent notificationIntent  = new Intent(this,CustomActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.happiness_icon);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Positive Minds");
    mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);


    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this
            .getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below mentioned code to fix this.

```
if(calendar1.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0)
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```